# On the liminf and limsup of the fourier coefficient of non-increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}_+$ be a non-negative non-increasing function such that $\int_0^1 xf(x)\,dx<\infty$. Define $A(b)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\sin(bx)f(x)\,dx$. Is it possible that $\limsup_{b\to\infty} A(b)>0$ and $\liminf_{b\to\infty} A(b)=0$ simultaneously?

Note: Using periodicity of $\sin$ function, it can be shown that $A(b)\ge 0$ for any $b$.

Comment: Why is $\int\limits_0^1 xf(x) x < \infty$ relevant here? Do you really mean $\int_0^\infty$ ? Although even that seems unnecessary given that $f$ is non-increasing and hence bounded.

Comment: If $f(x) = x^{-3/2}$ then $xf(x)$ is integrable over $(0,1]$ but $f$ is not bounded.

Comment: @RRL, thanks for the example

Comment: Unfortunately I misread this as $\lim_{b \to 0}$ in which case the limit is always $0$ by dominated convergence.

Answer (score 2):

Since  $|e^{-x} f(x)| < f(a)e^{-x}$ for $x \geqslant a > 0$, it follows that $e^{-x}f(x)$ is integrable over $[a,\infty)$ and by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma

$$\lim_{b \to \infty}\int_a^\infty e^{-x} \sin(bx)f(x) \, dx = 0$$

If the limit of the integral over $[0,\infty)$ fails to converge to $0$, then the problem arises from the behavior near $x = 0$.

Since $xf(x)$ is integrable over $[0,1]$ and $f$ is monotone we can only conclude that $f(x) = o(x^{-2})$ as $x \to 0$. It is possible that $e^{-x}f(x)$ is not integrable over $[0,1]$ and the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma cannot be invoked. That leaves the possibility that $\limsup_{b\to \infty}A(b) \neq \liminf_{b\to \infty}A(b) \neq 0$.

However, I suspect that $\limsup_{b \to \infty} A(b) > \liminf_{b \to \infty} A(b) = 0$ may not be possible.

For example with $f(x) = 1/x$ we have

$$A(b) = \int_0^\infty e^{-x} \frac{\sin(bx)}{x} \, dx = \arctan (b),$$

and $\limsup_{b \to \infty}A(b) = \liminf _{b \to \infty}A(b) = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: thanks for your response. Yes I posted the question thinking about the critical case that you mentioned. I also came up with 1/x example but I do not have a general way to prove or disprove my claim.

Comment: @Ribhu:  I guess I just covered the obvious first steps. Is there a particular reason that you are interested in this?